# How to enable logging in WinSCP script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, logging, console, winscp

I want to logging all information when WinSCP script shows in console to log file. I try to use output redirection, but log file remains empty.

```
D:\Programs\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe /script=sync.txt > log.txt
```

Also I tried to add `/console` parameter, but result is the same.

*P.S. Using `/log` option is not very useful for me, because it write too much incomprehensible information.*

Comment: Straight from the WinSCP website. **winscp.exe: Main executable, supports both GUI and console operation;** and **winscp.com: Console interface tool, supports console operation only, allows input/output redirection.**

Comment: Squashman, Using com-executable logging works fine. Thank you for help;

Comment: @Squashman Would you post it as an answer to close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`winscp.exe` is a *GUI* application. It *does not* have a standard output that can be redirected.

For your purposes, there's `winscp.com` which is a *console* application. And so it *does* have a standard output that can be redirected.

```
D:\Programs\WinSCP\WinSCP.com /script=sync.txt > log.txt
```

Read about [WinSCP executables](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables).

---

You may also be interested in using ["reduced" session logging](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#logging) (WinSCP 5.14 and newer only):

```
D:\Programs\WinSCP\WinSCP.com /script=sync.txt /loglevel=-1 /log=log.log
```

Or [XML logging](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/logging_xml):

```
D:\Programs\WinSCP\WinSCP.com /script=sync.txt /xmllog=log.xml
```

Both options can be used with `winscp.exe` too, but for scripting, it generally makes sense to use `winscp.com`.